# how to have Go accept web requests

Tags: go

I don't have the exact terminology so stay with me.

For php when a request comes in, say to `http://api.example.com/users/42`, Apache redirects the request to the appropriate directory.

In Go, how would I capture the `http://api.example.com/users/42` and then serve the output, such as JSON?  Would I use the net package and listen on port 80?

I'm sure this is pretty elementary, but I don't think I have the correct terminology hence why it's a little hard to look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the Wiki, specially [`this`](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) article, also check this excelent book : [Build Web Application with Golang](https://github.com/Unknwon/build-web-application-with-golang_EN)

basic idea is :

```
package main

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/users/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

Note that to listen on port `80` you have to be root.

Comment: This answer also led me to this framework for doing exactly this: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux